# Java JSoup: what does this message mean?

Tags: html-parsing, jsoup

I want to use the JSoup project to validate html fragments.  All I really want to know is whether the fragment is valid HTML or not.
JSoup does return errors if a flag is set on the parser.  But when I run the parser on this fragment:

```
"This is a <br/> test"
```

I get this error message **"Self closing flag not acknowledged"**
I don't know what this means or whether it is really intended to be an error, since the `ParseError` class has only two properties, a text and an error position.

Also, it seems inconsistent.  This, for example is OK:

```
"This is a <br> test"
```

This is also OK:

```
"<br/> This is a test"
```

The key to generating this error message seems to be plain text appearing before the 
 tag with self-closing in the tag (`<br/>`).

Does anyone know what, exactly, this message means and why it is an error and not a warning, and why this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error `Self closing flag not acknowledged` is a bit cryptic - it is defined as that in the HTML5 spec. The actual error in the HTML is that a `br` tag should not have a trailing `/`. HTML5 is not XML and empty tags are correctly written like `<br>`, `<img>`, **not** like `<br />`, `<image />` etc.

The text of the error means that the parser "did not acknowledge" the slash as a useful token.

That you're not seeing the error generated when the br tag is at the start of the string looks like a bug.